# How can I pass a function with arguments when the arguments aren't known yet?

Tags: python-3.x

This code does not run. It fails during the run(gate) function. The first error I get is from the `.__name__` call. This isn't my main issue, so I'm not particularly worried about this error yet

The second error I get is in the last line of run(gate). The error message says gate is not callable.

I believe my actual issue is with the structure of my program. Am I misunderstanding (or misapplying) some object-oriented principles? I would appreciate it if somebody could provide an example or a correction to my code for a better way of structuring it. Thank you!

main.py

```
import builtins
import logic

print("Select a logic gate:") 
print("1) AND") 
print("2) NAND") 
print("3) OR") 
print("4) NOR") 
print("Q) Quit Program") 
logicGate = input() 
if(int(logicGate) == 1):
   run(logic.andGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 2):
   run(logic.nandGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 3):
   run(logic.orGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 4):
   run(logic.norGate) 
elif(logicGate.lower() == 'q'):
   prog = 'n' 
else:
   print("Invalid input. Please try again") 

def toBool(s): 
   if s == 'True': 
      return True 
   elif s == 'False': 
      return False 
   else: 
      raise ValueError

def run(gate):
   print(gate.__name__ + " Gate function") 
   print("Enter value for 'a'") 
   valA = input() 
   print("Enter value for 'b'") 
   valB = input()
   print("Result: " + str(gate(toBool(valA), toBool(valB))))
```

And logic.py

```
def andGate(a, b):
   if(a and b):
      return True
   else:
      return False

def nandGate(a,b):
   if(a and b):
      return False
   else:
      return True

def orGate(a, b):
   if(a or b):
      return True
   else:
      return False

def norGate(a, b):
   if(a or b):
      return False
   else:
      return True
```

Comment: Works perfectly, if you move `run` and `toBool` to the top of the script, just after the imports.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah even so, why str? when you print results?? If its Boolean object shouldnt it be an interger... 0 or 1... or true or false... point is.... thats going to raise that ValueError

Comment: @scriptso `>>> str(True) ;
'True'`

Comment: righ tbut strings always true lol... even .... x = "false" ... is true

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ oh dude durp.... notice anything wrong in how the exception was madE?

Comment: @scriptso What are you trying to say? Just post an answer, I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅIm saying it built incorrectly, just removing it... or build it appropriately ... Mr  Francheti would have spotted that at first glance lol

Answer (score 0):

move your defs under imports and just remove the else: raise.... etc ect part... itnot used correctly.

```
import builtins
import logic

def toBool(s): 
   if s == 'True': 
      return True 
   elif s == 'False': 
      return False 


def run(gate):
   print(gate.__name__ + " Gate function") 
   print("Enter value for 'a'") 
   valA = input() 
   print("Enter value for 'b'") 
   valB = input()
   print("Result: " + str(gate(toBool(valA), toBool(valB))))

print("Select a logic gate:") 
print("1) AND") 
print("2) NAND") 
print("3) OR") 
print("4) NOR") 
print("Q) Quit Program") 
logicGate = input() 
if(int(logicGate) == 1):
   run(logic.andGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 2):
   run(logic.nandGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 3):
   run(logic.orGate) 
elif(int(logicGate) == 4):
   run(logic.norGate) 
elif(logicGate.lower() == 'q'):
   prog = 'n' 
else:
   print("Invalid input. Please try again")
```

Comment: Sorry no pep! hope its not 2 garbled.